# Select option is returning only one option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select option with two colors, red and blue. When I choose red it should set background color to red, and if I choose blue it should set background color to blue. The problem is that whatever I choose it sets background color to red.

```
<select id ="selectColor">
    <option >none</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectColor").change(function () {
        if ($(this).text != "red") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
        if ($(this).text !="blue")
         {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `$(this).text()`...

Comment: I tried but still same problem

Comment: I think there is no need to downvote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#selectColor").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "red") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
    else if ($(this).val() !="blue")
        {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
});
});
```

With val() you get the value of the option. If you are using "text" you get all the texts of all options, and your if breaks

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's first setting your background to blue, and then red because `$(this).text` is equal to neither. It's likely `undefined`.

You're looking for the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method, to extract the `value` attribute.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function () {
  $("#selectColor").on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = val;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectColor">
    <option value="">none</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is shortest and easiest example :

```html
<select onchange="javascript:document.body.style.backgroundColor=this.value;">
    <option >none</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `text` property on a jQuery object will always be a function. It will never be either of the stings you are testing against, so all your conditions will match. The colour will be changed to blue, then immediately changed to red.

You want to use `val()` not `text`.

Answer (score 1):

Use val() instead of text();

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#selectColor").change(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() != "red") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
     if ($(this).val() !="blue")
        {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f6owbz3a/)

Comment: Great, you fixed the problem, but _why_ does it work? ;)

Comment: I have updated the answer and for a small change I suppose an questioner can look why val be used instead of text...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using jQuery : -

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#selectColor").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "red") {
            $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
        } else {
            $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
```

See this JS Fiddle as an example - [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pspe6yhj/)
    });